# setChannel is undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a simple command that moves the mentioned user back and forth, but I get an error message that `setChannel` is undefined.

Here is my code:

```
module.exports ={
    name:'bully',
    description: "something",
    execute(message, args, Discord, client){
       const GuildMember = message.mentions.users.first();
       const channel1 = GuildMember.voiceChannel;
       const channel2 = '785599712677462016';
       GuildMember.voice.setChannel('channel1');
       GuildMember.voice.setChannel('channel2');
       GuildMember.voice.setChannel('channel1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GuildMember` is not what it's supposed to be. Here, it’s actually defined as an instance of [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User).

To fix it, change it from [`MessageMentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) to [`MessageMentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) so you get a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)

```js
const GuildMember = message.mentions.members.first()
```